# How to INNER JOIN 2 or 3 different database with same table in one query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

im trying to search data from different database with the same table. instead of doing the long cut query, how can I INNER JOIN the 2 different database in single query. thank you.

```
Set db = OpenDatabase(DbName, False, True, "MS Access;PWD=1234")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * AVAILABLE_STAFF WHERE staff_id = '" & Search_ID & "'", dbOpenSnapshot, dbOptimistic)

With rs
    If .RecordCount = 0 Then
    Else
       'INSERT DATA TO LISTVIEW
    End If
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

db.Close
Set db = Nothing

Set db = OpenDatabase(DbName1, False, True, "MS Access;PWD=1234")

 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * AVAILABLE_STAFF WHERE staff_id = '" & Search_ID & "'", dbOpenSnapshot, dbOptimistic)
With rs

    If .RecordCount = 0 Then

    Else
    'INSERT DATA TO LISTVIEW
    End If
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

db.Close
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: I really don't think this is something that should be tagged `VBA` :-) Have you tried `SELECT A.col1, B.col2
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.key = B.FK;`?

Comment: hi sorry to bother you hauns and thanks for the reply. I'm not familiar with the INNER JOIN that's why I post this and base on your reply, to be honest with you, I don't understand A.col1 stands for. I saw this post before but I cant still get it.

Comment: Create 4th database, link all relevant tables and create the query

Comment: hi santosh can you give me an example how? thanks

Comment: or can you enlighten me on this query? SELECT A.col1, B.col2 FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.key = B.FK

Comment: What does your E/R diagram look like? What are the relations in your database? ONE TO MANY, MANY TO MANY?

Comment: here's my code so far. 'code' Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ds.* FROM DOCUMENT_STATUS AS ds LEFT JOIN [MS Access;DATABASE=" & Completed & ";PWD=pwd].[DOCUMENT_STATUS] AS cds ON ds.refnum=cds.refnum", dbOpenDynaset, dbOptimistic) 'code' I have a record on both database. but the only one record shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't show any E/R and it was not 100% clear what you asked for this answer might not be as good as you wish.

1. Change the title of your question. "How to INNER JOIN 2 or 3
   different database with same table in one query" is confusing! You
   "join tables in a database", you don't "join databases with same
   table in one query"!
2. I can't figure out this one `[MS Access;DATABASE=" & Completed & ";PWD=pwd].[DOCUMENT_STATUS]`? Guess it creates some kind of table?
3. You are only selecting results from your first alias table, `[ds]`?
   Have you tried:

```
SELECT ds.*, cds.*
        FROM DOCUMENT_STATUS AS ds
        LEFT JOIN [MS Access;DATABASE=" & Completed & ";PWD=pwd].[DOCUMENT_STATUS] AS cds 
        ON ds.refnum=cds.refnum
```

in your case you could also do `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT ds.*, cds.*`.